# Class requiring itself to construct itself

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

First please understand that I may have this totally wrong which is why google isn't help.
I am trying to construct the following object: M3Tools

```
public class M3UTrack {

    private String path;
    private int secondsDuration;
    private String label;

    //Get and set of these omitted

    public M3UTrack()
    {
        path = null;
        label = null;
        secondsDuration = 0;
    }
    public M3UTrack(M3UTrack t)
    {
        // Creating a track as a duplicate of the track you pass it?
        path = new String(t.getPath());
        label = new String(t.getLabel());
        secondsDuration = t.getSecondsDuration();    
    }
```

From what I gather if I was to use the second constructor I would have to pass an object of itself??? It's throwing me in a loop. There are other classes involved.

Comment: Do you want to construct an M3Tools object or an M3UTrack object? I cannot see any code for the mentioned M3Tools.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You need to show how you are calling the second constructor, so that we can understand how "it's throwing (you) in a loop".

Comment: BTW: maing a copy of path and label strings in that copy constructor is rather strange. If it is not needed it can be optimized. If it is needed (which is a bad practice to rely on String object idendity) then you need to add comment.

Comment: @Atuos my question is: What is it called and how do I correctly initialise this class?

Comment: Sorry I mean instantiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `M3UTrack(M3UTrack t)` is a so called copy constructor, because it creates a new instance but copies the values of the other. If you want to create a first/new instance you would probably use the first version. The class and constructor are public, so nothing should stop you from writing

```
M3UTrack t = new M3UTrack();  // default constructor
t.setPath(...); t.setLabel(...); t.setDurationSeconds(10); // fill data
M3UTrack s = new M3UTrack(t); // sample usage of copy constructor
```

If you have problems with this you need to show us your code and your error message. It is a compile time or runtime error? If it is a stacktrace please also tell us which line numbers are involved.

BTW: you might want to add another constructor which alles to specify all mandatory fields, so you dont need to use the setters. This has the advantage that you never have a "half" constructed object. When you omit the setters then you are using a pattern called immutable object:

```
public M3UTrack(String path, String label, int duration)
{
    this.path = path;
    this.label = label;
    this.secondsDuration = duration;
}
```

And then construct it like:

```
M3UTrack t = new M3UTrack("file.mp3", "Songs", 10/*sec*/);
```

Comment: Thank you this likely makes sense, this was part of uni work. 
So A. I did not want to post the whole code due to IP concerns.
B. I obviously did not write this bit.

The following are relevent parts from a class called playlist
Which holds a list of 
`private List <M3UTrack> theListOfTracks;`

Later on add method is called

`void add(M3UTrack m) {theListOfTracks.add(m);}`

In regards to error message, well I haven't compiled it because I need to first solve how to initialise this class.

Comment: I mean Instantiated, not initialise

Answer (score 0):

You can perfectly reference an object of a class you are defining. If not, how could you [create copy constructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)#Copy_constructors)? which, by the way, is exactly what you are doing at `public M3UTrack(M3UTrack t)`.

From Wikipedia:

> Copy constructors define the actions performed by the compiler when
>   copying class objects. A copy constructor **has one formal parameter
>   that is the type of the class** (the parameter may be a reference to an
>   object)...

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, you'd construct an instance of M3Track and set the properties on it. If you want to make a copy, you have the given copy constructor as an *option*.

Answer (score 0):

This construct has name "copy constructor"and is used in specyfic places. Normal use first, no arguments construcror.

Usage of copy constructor, like name says, is "between" two objects (old and new), seems Your use case never occur (sorry for spelling, this from phone)

`M3UTrack theNew = new M3UTrack(theOld)`